# Object.defineProperty in for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, object, for-loop, defineproperty

In my code I have an object,

```
var obj = {
    item1: {
        coords: {
            A: new Point(905.76, 1626.67),
            //...
        },
        inf: {
            //...
        }
    },

    item2: {
        coords: {
            A: new Point(1259.25, 1634.50),
            //...
        },
        inf: {
            //...
        }
    },
}
```

And I would like to define some properties like that:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj.item1.inf, "corner", {
    get() {
        var x = obj.item1.coords.A.x;
        var y = obj.item1.coords.A.y;
        return new Point(x, y);
    }
})
Object.defineProperty(obj.item2.inf, "corner", {
    get() {
        var x = obj.item2.coords.A.x;
        var y = obj.item2.coords.A.y;
        return new Point(x, y);
    }
})
```

It works fine for me, but it's only a piece of code. I thought, that it'll be nicer to make my code shorter and I decided to instead of just copying and renamed it uses a for loop like that:

```
for (item in obj) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj[item].inf, "corner", {
        get() {
            var x = obj[item].coords.A.x;
            var y = obj[item].coords.A.y;
            return new Point(x, y);
        }
    })
}
```

But it just one issue. I'm getting the same values for all items inf from the last one. Is there any possibility to solve this problem?

Comment: Not certain gather issue correctly. Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the lack of closure in your loop (you can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)). The simplest solution is to define your loop variable with `let` which creates block scope variable:

```
for (let item in obj) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj[item].inf, "corner", {
        get() {
            var x = obj[item].coords.A.x;
            var y = obj[item].coords.A.y;
            return new Point(x, y);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: That's it's working as I wanted.